# When on interval there is smooth measure with integral moments?

Tags: measure-theory, moment-problem

Let $a<b$. When there is a smooth, strictly positive function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb Z, n\geq 0$ we have:

$$m_n(d\mu):=\int_{a}^bx^nd\mu \in\mathbb Z,$$

where $d\mu=f(x)dx$.

When $a=-1, b=1$ this is clearly impossible as $0<m_n(d\mu)$ and $m_n(d\mu)\to0$.

When $a=-2, b=2$ there is non-trivial example

\begin{equation}
    \dfrac 1{2\pi}\int\limits_{-2}^2\sqrt{4-x^2}x^k=
    \begin{cases}
      C_{k/2}, & \text{if}\ k\ \text{even} \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
Here $C_k$ is Catalan numbers.

When $a=0, b=+\infty$ we can take $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

> Can we construct such a measure when $b-a < 4$?

Comment: Is the key point of this that you want all the $m_n$ to be integers?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: For what it is worth, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975300/speed-of-random-sampling-from-distribution-in-r has an example with $a=0,b=4$ (in fact all the moments are Catalan numbers) and there may be simpler examples

Comment: Uniform distribution doesn't work! Because integral of $x^k$ has $k$ as denominator.